Remove duplicated from multidimensional array
Have an array with this expression $products[] = $product[$category_id][$product_id]:
$products = array(
    33 => array(
        31 => array(
            'model' => 'Product 4',
            'product_id' => 31,
            'sku' => '',
            'ean' => '1234',
            'price' => '80.0000'
        ),
        8733 => array(
            'model' => 'qqq',
            'product_id' => 8733,
            'sku' => '',
            'ean' => '1000',
            'price' => '344.6281'
        )
    ),
    25 => array(
        30 => array(
            'model' => 'Product 3',
            'product_id' => 30,
            'sku' => '',
            'ean' => '250',
            'price' => '50.4132'
        ),
        31 => array(
            'model' => 'Product 4',
            'product_id' => 31,
            'sku' => '',
            'ean' => '1234',
            'price' => '80.0000'
        )
    )
);

I need remove duplicated product in php and result must be:
$products = array(
    33 => array(
        8733 => array(
            'model' => 'qqq',
            'product_id' => 8733,
            'sku' => '',
            'ean' => '1000',
            'price' => '344.6281'
        )
    ),
    25 => array(
        30 => array(
            'model' => 'Product 3',
            'product_id' => 30,
            'sku' => '',
            'ean' => '250',
            'price' => '50.4132'
        ),
        31 => array(
            'model' => 'Product 4',
            'product_id' => 31,
            'sku' => '',
            'ean' => '1234',
            'price' => '80.0000'
        ),
    )
);

I have tried this:
$cleared_products = array();

        foreach ($products as $category_id => $category_products) {
            foreach ($category_products as $product_id => $product) {
                if (isset($cleared_products[$category_id][$product_id])) {
                    
                    unset($products[$category_id][$product_id]);
                } else {
                    
                    $cleared_products[$category_id][$product_id] = $product;
                }
            }
        }

But does not work...
Edited to explain why I need that
I need to generate XML and no products can be duplicated. It doesn't matter that they belong to a different category. XML recipient rules...

Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307674/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-php

I tried everything I found here before posting...

Why is the removed product considered duplicate? What's the rule?

I need to generate XML and no products can be duplicated. It doesn't matter that they belong to a different category. XML recipient rules. And it's funny that some people put "-" without understanding the essence of the question :)

it's funny that some people put "-" without understanding the essence of the question...well TBH you didn't put the "essence of the question" into the question, so what do you expect? People vote on what they can see, not the things you never mentioned. If that point about the XML is something you regard as an essential piece of context which might affect the solution, then it should have been there at the start. At the very least you should [edit] your post now to include it, rather than hiding it down in the comments :-)

@K.B. if categories are not important, it's maybe better to flatten the array first and remove duplicates then. You could always add a category_id if needed to your product.

@ADyson what I expect was simply asked. If I asked how to remove duplicate products from an array and you don't understand, just ask and it will be explained to you so you understand. Many people understood immediately what was needed, but unfortunately some did not :D Thank for all who can understand a question... :-)

FWIW I didn't downvote you, I'm just replying to your "essence of the question" remark. Now you're saying there's nothing wrong with the question, yet your earlier remark implied people had misunderstood it. If several people misunderstood it then realistically it probably isn't all that clear. No offence meant. Of you're perhaps assuming that's why people downvoted you...they could have had other reasons (for example "does not work" isn't a useful problem description...people can't tell if there was an error, or what unexpected result you saw, or whatever). :-)

P.S. If I asked how to remove duplicate products from an array and you don't understand, just ask... shingo already asked what the rule was for considering something was a duplicate. I believe that's what prompted you to issue the clarification.

P.S. And it was immediately answered... and what's wrong with that? :) If someone is too lazy to read carefully, maybe this is their problem and not mine? :-)

The problem was ambiguity, which of course no amount of careful reading can resolve. The answer made an assumption and happened to be correct about it, but could easily not have been

The problem with your code is that you check if the product exists within it's category. In your example the duplicate product is in two categories.
We can adjust it easily by keeping track of the ID you added.
$cleared_products = array();
$productIds = array();

foreach ($products as $category_id => $category_products) {
    foreach ($category_products as $product_id => $product) {
        if (in_array($product_id, $productIds)) {
            continue;
        } else {
            $productIds[] = $product_id;
            $cleared_products[$category_id][$product_id] = $product;
        }
    }
}

Important note: You don't have control out of which category the item will be filtered
So the expected result is not matched with this code. If you define the priority of categories and sort on this, you can delete it where wanted.

Solution
$products = array(
    33 => array(
        31 => array(
            'model' => 'Product 4',
            'product_id' => 31,
            'sku' => '',
            'ean' => '1234',
            'price' => '80.0000'
        ),
        8733 => array(
            'model' => 'qqq',
            'product_id' => 8733,
            'sku' => '',
            'ean' => '1000',
            'price' => '344.6281'
        )
    ),
    25 => array(
        30 => array(
            'model' => 'Product 3',
            'product_id' => 30,
            'sku' => '',
            'ean' => '250',
            'price' => '50.4132'
        ),
        31 => array(
            'model' => 'Product 4',
            'product_id' => 31,
            'sku' => '',
            'ean' => '1234',
            'price' => '80.0000'
        )
    )
);

// Create a new array to store unique products
$uniqueProducts = array();

foreach ($products as $parentKey => $items) {
    foreach ($items as $productId => $product) {
        $found = false;
        // Check if the product already exists in the uniqueProducts array
        foreach ($uniqueProducts as $existingItems) {
            if (isset($existingItems[$productId]) && $existingItems[$productId] == $product) {
                $found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        // If the product is not found, add it to the uniqueProducts array
        if (!$found) {
            $uniqueProducts[$parentKey][$productId] = $product;
        }
    }
}

// Output the unique products array
print_r($uniqueProducts);

Output:
Array
(
    [33] => Array
        (
            [31] => Array
                (
                    [model] => Product 4
                    [product_id] => 31
                    [sku] => 
                    [ean] => 1234
                    [price] => 80.0000
                )

            [8733] => Array
                (
                    [model] => qqq
                    [product_id] => 8733
                    [sku] => 
                    [ean] => 1000
                    [price] => 344.6281
                )

        )

    [25] => Array
        (
            [30] => Array
                (
                    [model] => Product 3
                    [product_id] => 30
                    [sku] => 
                    [ean] => 250
                    [price] => 50.4132
                )

        )

)

Online Execution: 3v4l
Explanation:

Create a new array called $uniqueProducts to store the products without duplicates.
Loop through each product in the original $products array.
Check if the product already exists in $uniqueProducts by comparing its product_id and details.
If the product isn't found (i.e., it’s not a duplicate), add it to $uniqueProducts.
The final result is an array with only unique products, keeping the same structure as the original array.


Writing you own 'in_array' loop instead of using the function is strongly discouraged. Especially when its already nested inside two other foreaches.

@Wimanicesir I agree. Using in_array is recommended as it might be more efficient. I was about to update my solution, but I noticed that our answers would be almost identical, so I decided to leave it as it is.
